# Oops Something Bad Happened to the chat error page

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, error-message

The [chat error page](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/error) has a very primitive layout compared to the other [error pages](https://stackoverflow.com/error).

On closer inspection, the error (from the console is)

> jQuery is not defined

It is unfortunate that [jQuery](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492) is not defined.

Comment: They are A/B testing with and without jQuery ...

Comment: The cat's cuter :D

Comment: @MsYvette If Jquery was there the humans could have taken over bityhjgvdckvsdfdv ...

Comment: Sorry for that ^, my cat took over the keyboard

Comment: @BhargavRao that's funny :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chat's error page is an almost completely static page; in particular it doesn't dynamically choose the correct CSS file for the site. It was still trying to use the old chat.MSO CSS which I finally deleted the other day.

I changed it to use an existing file again. Not that the difference is big for such a simple page :)

Regarding your jQuery point: I'm not sure whether that's meant to be a joke, but that page doesn't use any JavaScript at all. If you actually see that error, it must be from a browser extension you have installed, not from chat.

Comment: Thanks balpha for your speedy response. I don't know anything about JS. I opened console and I saw that error. I'll re check it when I go back home. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Also balpha, another small problem. The favicon is the MSE icon instead of the MSO icon. Not a large bug for another report. :)