# Attempting to view bookmarked chat conversations causes a 500 error

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, error-message

Whenever I try to view a bookmarked chat conversation, like [this one](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/conversation/shog-edits-tunas-message), the page sits loading for a while before eventually throwing a 500 error:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HB8ht.png]

The error only occurs on [chat.stackoverflow.com](https://chat.stackoverflow.com); it doesn't appear on either of the other two chat domains ([chat.stackexchange.com](https://chat.stackexchange.com) and chat.meta.stackexchange.com).

I'm not the only person who this has happened to; [a couple other users in SOCVR said they saw it also](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/30954826#30954826).

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome 51.0 Windows 7.

Comment: Can repro in Chrome 53 Windows 10

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome 51.0 / Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: The machine works mightedly to dig it out of terabytes of "how are you doing" and "here's another one sucks" chatter.  To trigger a SQL Server timeout, the custom "oops" message is SE's version of "we ought to work on it tomorrow".  It won't be tomorrow.

Comment: No repro on Chrome 51 / Windows 10 Pro x64. Perhaps this has been fixed?

Comment: Notice that the favicon on the error page also uses the stack exchange favicon, and not the SO favicon

Comment: @Ferrybig Apparently [by design](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313009/oops-something-bad-happened-to-the-chat-error-page#comment285828_313021)

Comment: @cybermonkey still happening here.

Comment: <strikethrough>It's not happening for me anymore on Safari 9.1 / OS X 10.11.4.</strikethrough>  Nevermind, now it is again.

Comment: It is happening on my windows 7 machine on firefox also

Comment: @Braiam Now I can repro.. seems to be in the evening (GMT). My guess is that some internal cache isn't working correctly (which is cleared in the morning, probably at 3am GMT when many of the other scripts are run).

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome 44 on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: No repro, chrome current, win 7 (currently tooth and nail with auto w10 updater).

Comment: You bookmarked _"Shog edits Tuna's message"_?

Comment: Now no repro again.. something is seriously amiss.

Comment: reproduced on firefox 44 windows 7

Comment: No repro, FF 46.0.1 OSX El Capitane

Comment: No repro Opera 37.0.2178.54, Windows 10.

Comment: No repro Chrome Version 51.0.2704.79 m Windows 7 Pro 64 bit.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah, that was the only thing I ever bookmarked, so I linked it.  (I was testing [a chatbot](http://github.com/NobodyNada/chatbot), and then Shog9 edited Tunaki's message, but the chatbot noticed that.)